# Key Check Value standard practice for asymmetric cryptography?

Tags: public-key, keys

I'm looking for a *standard*, or sound *industry practice*, for the equivalent of a Key Check Value, applied to the private key of a public key algorithm, like ECDSA.

For DES or 3DES keys, practice (as worded e.g. in [EMV Card Personalization Specification](https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=20)) is:

> 6.1.5 **Key Check Value**
>   *Purpose*: The data is used to prove that a card/processor has access to a
>   specific DES key value.
>   *Format*: Binary, 3 bytes
>   *Contents*: The three leftmost bytes of the result of encrypting eight bytes of zeros by the DES key concerned.

Notice that the above definition is slightly wrong: the KCV as defined does not prove anything beyond knowledge of the KCV. The actual purpose (and the one I'm interested about) is to guard against a wrong value of the key, either accidental, or deliberate from one participant in a scheme where the key is rebuilt from shared secrets (for simplicity, assume that's by XOR of the components, and that at least one participant does not cheat).

Comment: Public key fingerprints are used by SSH (and other protocols).

Comment: For your secret sharing scenario my first instinct is using an all-or-nothing transform on the plaintext together with some redundancy, similar to OAEP. Should probably the unkeyed equivalent of a *strong* pseudo-random-permutation.

Comment: For my modest knowledge, in PKI, KCV sound to be irrelevant. For symetric system KCV is nothing than the encryption of a given tag to be convinced of using the secret key without knowing its value.In ECDSA encrypting twice the same message gives two distinct results

Comment: Note that the standard KCV for symmetric keys leaks the first 3 (or more) bytes of plaintext for CTR mode with an initial counter set to all zeros. That's not a good choice. For symmetric keys a hash is a better option, and for RSA I think it is quite common to perform a hash over the modulus. I don't see how you could do this for ECDSA however. Maybe a hash over the x coordinate of the public key is possible, if I'm not mistaken it's relatively fast to calculate the public key point from the secret S given the domain parameters. Can somebody confirm that this is a good idea?

Answer (score 3):

PKCS10 looks like relevant industry practice for private keys.

See "Note 2" at page 4,
[Certification Request Syntax Specification - RFC 2986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986):
The signature on the certification request prevents an entity from requesting a certificate with another party's public key.

That is, soneone requesting a certificate on a public key demonstrates his knowledge of corresponding private key by producing a signature verifiable with the public key from PKCS10 request.

Another technique could be found at Join protocol,
[Direct Anonymous Attestation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/205)
for Trusted Platform Module chip.
It could be considered a proof that TPM "has access" to "keys" $f_0$ and $f_1$.

Comment: That indeed matches the question as asked. However there's a significant issue: it's big!

Comment: @fgrieu  It's clear that message size is of primary concern in smartcards. Any signature or a proof of knowledge would fit this idea. Let's wait, hopefully someone would suggest another (of small size) solution.